# Reset BIOS password lenovo

Tags: bios, passwords, lenovo-laptop

When I try to remove the BIOS password from my laptop, ask me to enter the new password and confirm it, i just press Enter key in the two steps after that.
I can't open my laptop because require me to enter the BIOS when enter the old password don't accept it or when i try to press Enter key, Can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn off the computer.
2. Remove the battery pack.
3. Remove CMOS Battery for 2min
4. Turn on the computer and wait until the POST ends. After the POST ends, the password prompt does not appear. The POP has been removed.