# Reset bios password of Lenovo fails (asks for password and PIM)

Tags: bios, passwords, battery, cmos, pim

I've got an used Thinkpad which asks for a password. Since the password prompt is a black screen with just the letters `Password:` in white I assume it's a BIOS password. To remove it I followed instructions such as [these](https://superuser.com/a/1016379/211878). I opened the laptop, removed the battery and the CMOS battery, and after a couple minutes I reconnected them. After doing this I boot it up. It makes a short beep and then very shortly flashes on the screen:

> 0251: System CMOS CHecksum bad - Default configuration used.

And after that it proceeds to the same screen as before, which asks for the password. If I simply leave it blank and hit enter it then asks for a PIM. I leave that empty as well, but as you can see below it refuses access.

Does anybody know what I can do to remove/bypass the password prompt? I don't care about the data on the laptop (I will probably flash it and install some Linux distro on it).

[image]

Comment: Can you enter Bios without entering a password? If so, it's not a Bios password. I rather think this is a Hard Disk password, actually.

Comment: That is not a ThinkPad password setup at all (not on any ThinkPad I have seen) . Can you ask the seller?

Comment: Most modern laptops it's not actually possible to bypass the BIOS password. In your case it you are successfully resetting the configuration,, hence the message that the default configuration will be used. The password prompt in question isn't a UEFI/BIOS password.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [VeraCrypt full-disk encryption bootloader](https://github.com/search?q=%22Wrong+password%2C+PIM+or+hash%22&type=code) prompt. If you don't know the password, you cannot access what's currently on the disk – only erase it.

Normally, VeraCrypt does not make permanent changes to the disk or the computer itself; the loader that you're seeing is just from the disk's MBR much like the actual OS normally would be. This shouldn't stop you from booting from USB sticks or other media.

Boot from any USB stick, wipe the disk and reinstall the OS. If you can get it to boot Linux from USB, just overwrite the first few MB of the disk (`head -c 64M /dev/zero > /dev/sdX`). A new MBR will be created later during OS installation.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got an used ThinkPad which asks for a password. Since the password prompt is a black screen with just the letters Password: in white I assume it's a BIOS password. To remove it I followed instructions such as these. I opened the laptop, removed the battery and the CMOS battery, and after a couple minutes I reconnected them. After doing this I boot it up. It makes a short beep and then very shortly flashes on the screen:
>
> [image]

The prompt in question, more than likely, is a VeraCrypt prompt.  I found zero instances of PIM with relation to ThinkPads but found several instances of Personal Iterations Multiplier (PIM) connected to VeraCrypt.

> Does anybody know what I can do to remove/bypass the password prompt?

You would have to replace the HDD.  The drive is encrypted with VeraCrypt and unless you know the password cannot be used to boot to an operating system without formatting it.

> I don't care about the data on the laptop (I will probably flash it and install some Linux distro on it).

It's good you don't care about the data on the laptop, since it's encrypted, and it's clear you don't know the password or the Personal Iterations Multiplier (PIM) required to decrypt the drive.

**The failure message by the way is indicating that password provided is incorrect, when used with the default PIM value of 98, thus the drive could not be decrypted.**

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as @user1686 - Is it not possible to format this hard disc and put Linux on it? Do I really have to get the hard drive out and buy a new one?

Comment: I now got into the bios, changed the boot order priority and booted Ubuntu from a USB-stick. The only thing I get to is a grub terminal though. Do you think it would be possible to format the hard disc from this point?